# Nested Pointer Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm calling the below Parse Query using the Parse Server Javascript API.  I have a class called **Device**, which has a pointer object to **Device_Type** which in turn has a pointer to **Manufacturer**.

I can successfully display the deviceID in inventoryItem, but get undefined for manufacturer, despite there being the relevant data in the JSON network return.

```
$scope.getDeviceItems = function () {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Device");
    query.include("Device_Type");
    query.include("Device_Type.Manufacturer");
        query.find({
            success: function (results) {
                $scope.deviceItems = [];
                for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var d = results[i].get("Device_Type");
                    var m = results[i].get("Device_Type.Manufacturer");
                    var inventoryItem = {
                        deviceID: d.get("Device_ID"),
                        manufacturer: m.get("Manufacturer_Name")
                    }
                };
            };
        };
    };
```

How would I correctly obtain the nested pointer data into manufacturer?

Here's a sample JSON Object:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "objectId": "q3D2myHG3e",
        "createdAt": "2017-07-30T22:28:05.035Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-09-19T20:40:05.580Z",
        "Device_Type": {
            "objectId": "Ksej3F2sdp5",
            "Device_Name": "Device 1",
            "createdAt": "2017-07-30T21:57:58.638Z",
            "updatedAt": "2017-08-08T20:20:14.397Z",
            "Manufacturer": {
                "objectId": "3NahYBNIiC",
                "Manufacturer_Name": "ABC Ltd",
                "createdAt": "2017-07-30T21:56:40.557Z",
                "updatedAt": "2017-07-30T22:13:07.425Z",
                "Devices": {
                    "__type": "Relation",
                    "className": "DeviceType"
                },
                "__type": "Object",
                "className": "DeviceManufacturer"
            },
            "__type": "Object",
            "className": "DeviceType"
        },
        ...
    }]
}
```

Comment: can you post your `json` data as well? I think you're messing up your success call. generally when you pass the `results` you should do something like `$scope.eurica = results.data` but I'm unsure. It'd be easier if you show me your actual data.

Comment: @ZombieChowder I've amended the question with the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.getDeviceItems = function () {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Device");
    query.include("Device_Type");
    query.include("Device_Type.Manufacturer");
        query.find({
            success: function (results) {
                $scope.deviceItems = [];
                for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var curResult = results[i];
                    var d = curResult.Device_Type;
                    var m = curResult.Device_Type.Manufacturer;
                    var inventoryItem = {
                        deviceID: d.Device_ID
                        manufacturer: m.Manufacturer_Name
                    }
                };
            };
        };
    };
```

Not sure why a map is being used a regular JS object as shown above would work easier (assuming find function just resolved with the JS object from parsing the JSON instead of turning it into a Map object)

Using a Map you need to call get twice as far as I can tell to resolve "deeper" keys.

```
$scope.getDeviceItems = function () {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Device");
    query.include("Device_Type");
    query.include("Device_Type.Manufacturer");
        query.find({
            success: function (results) {
                $scope.deviceItems = [];
                for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    var curResult = results[i];
                    var d = curResult.get('Device_Type');
                    var m = curResult.get('Device_Type').get('Manufacturer'); // or d.get('Manufacturer')
                    var inventoryItem = {
                        deviceID: d.get('Device_ID')
                        manufacturer: m.get('Manufacturer_Name')
                    }
                };
            };
        };
    };
```

```js
var testObj = new Map();
testObj.set('a', new Map());
testObj.get('a').set('b', 4);

console.log(testObj.get('a').get('b'))
```

Comment: Thanks.  Changing out `var m = results[i].get("Device_Type").get('Manufacturer');` did exactly what I needed.  Your further explanation is insightful though.  My knowledge level is lacking to answer the Map query sufficiently.  Its what the guide suggests: [http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#basic-queries](http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#basic-queries) .  Hopefully some more experienced Parse Devs will provide further insights.

Comment: @MrT Ah okay actually in the link there it has a bit about compound stuff using .get looks like you might be able to do `.get(["Device_Type.Manufacturer"])` http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#relational-queries scroll down from there to just above "Counting Objects" the docs don't seem to explicitly explain anywhere what can be done with .get though